# MiKTeX installation error: access violation issue

Tags: miktex

I have an issue on installing MiKTeX. I removed it from for some reason and tried to reinstall. I deleted the installation folder after the uninstall; and restarted my PC. I have tried many times,  but I see the same following error each times of installation. I deactivated my antivirus, but not working... Any solution is appreciated. Thanks

> extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
>
> extracting files from zapfding.cab...
>
> extracting files from zerohyph.tar.lzma...
>
> updating package definition directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages")...
>
> installed 3403 package definition files
>   visiting repository C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\mik99448...
>
> repository type: local package repository
>
> loading lightweight database...
>
> initexmf "--common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=1 --admin "--log-file=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose:
>
> An error occurred:
>
> source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp
>
> source line: 475
>
> message: The process terminated due to an access violation.
>
> info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe"

Comment: Add an issue (with more details about your OS) to the MiKTeX bug tracker at GitHub.